# how to reframe an UIView (already created) when added to a superview

Tags: swift, uiview, resize

Those lines don't the job each time they're called ....
if popUp is removed from superView then later re-added, popUp appears to be no more centered anymore neither framed as I want (90% of superView)

```
popUp = UIView(frame: CGRect(0,0,10,10))

superview.addSubview(popUp)
superview.centerView(popUp)
popUp.frame.size = superview.frame.size * 0.9
superview.layoutSubviews()
```

where centerView is an extension of UIView

```
 func centerView (_ view : UIView) {
    view.center.y = bounds.midX
    view.center.y = bounds.midY
}
```

and * is an extension of CGSize :

```
func * (size : CGSize, ratio : CGFloat) -> CGSize {return CGSize(width: size.width * ratio, height: size.height * ratio)}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Typo in `view.center.y = bounds.midX`.

Comment: Sorry what does your answer mean ?

Comment: Look at that line. You have a typo. You have your x and y mixed.

Comment: Thanks .... But it doesn't change anything ...Sometimes it's properly framed sometimes it isn't